# Adding duplicate items on page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this practice app I'm working on, the issue is that when I click 'add to cart' button for the same List Tile item, it shows error on the 'Cart' page. I understand why that is, the list doesn't allow the same item in it, and it says that each item should have unique ID, somebody know how to do that easily? Each of the code blocks is on a separate page.

Here is the cart model code, the provider function that adds the items to cart:

```
  class CartItemsModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> _cartItems = [];

  List<String> get cartItems => _cartItems;

  addCartItem(String item) {
    _cartItems.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Here's the code for the 'add to cart' button on a separate page. It is on each list til, sorry about the formatting:

```
return ListTile(
                                          trailing: Container(
                                            padding:
                                                EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                                            
                                          
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                                              onPressed: () =>
                                                
                                                  model.addCartItem(
                                                      "${name.name}\n${name.description}"),
                                            ),
                                          ),
```

And this is the builder on the cart page itself, which shows the error (red screen) if I click the button  above for the same list tile twice.

```
return Consumer<CartItemsModel>(
  builder: (c, model, _) => Scaffold(
```

Here is the error:

[image]

**UPDATE**

return ListTile(
trailing: Container(
padding:
EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
child: IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.add),

```
       onPressed: () =>  model.addCartItem( "${food.name}, Calories: 
       ${food.calories}, ${Uuid().v4()}")))
```

And on the next page where items are displayed:

```
  class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CartItemsModel>(
      builder: (c, model, _) => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Cart'),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              //on trailing i should have icon with clear function that will delete that item from the list
              children: model
                  .cartItems 
             
                  .map((e) => Dismissible(
                        onDismissed: (direction) {
                          setState(() {
                            model.deleteCartItem(e);
                          });
                        },
                        //ovo se vidi kada se swipuje
                        background: Container(color: Colors.white),
                       
                        key: Key(e),

                        
                        child: Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                          //it should be below in the title, so the 'e' would be that string
                            title: Text(e, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
                            trailing: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                              child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  //mozda ovo da stavim u onDismissed iz dismissible
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      model.deleteCartItem(e);
                                    });})))))).toList()))));}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart'

```
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
```

Change your adding logic to:

```
model.addCartItem("${name.name}\n${name.description}${Uuid().v4()}")
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the uuid like that without it being visible in my code? I've been trying to make it work, but I just can't seem to figure it out, it does work with the code above, but shows ugly uuid string.

Comment: Hi @arbiter, there is a way to "hide" the uuid string. Basically the uuid v4 string is a 36 characters string. So when you want to show the cart item without the ugly string, you must substring it by this function: cartItemWithUuid.substring(cartItemWithUuid.length - 36, cartItemWithUuid.length);

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you give me full code how that would work? Thank you a lot! I've been struggling with this for days, and even though it is probably simple to do, I don't know how.

Comment: The only issue is that I don't want to end up with 'duplicate keys' error, any way to go around that with this code?

Comment: With substringing this, I end up with only the Uuid, any way to reverse it? Also, not sure if I won't end up with 'duplicate keys' error. Any ideas how to fix that? Basically I want each string to be different (like with Uuid trick), but without the ugly code.

Comment: Actually, with the help of you guys, especially @Teddichiiwa on this particular issue, I managed to sort of 'fix' it just by removing the last 36 numbers and letters of Uuid:

   ` title: Text(e.substring(0, e.length - 36),`

and that seems to do the job.

Comment: sorry, I was use wrong index. I'm glad that you already fixed it :D

Comment: Yep, figured it out, after trying many things, this was probably the most simple solution to it, thank you for giving me the idea to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Well because of the stupid reputation system I cannot add a comment, but it seems like you are adding the item to a new list which looks at the unique ID's .. since those need to be unique, it gives an error when you add another item that has the same ID. Without more code to go on, that's where it's going wrong.

You can probably fix that by giving each item you enter into the new list a unique key. Instead of taking the key from the item you want to add. Or make a small adjustment to the existing key from the item you want to add, while adding them. To make sure the keys can never be the same.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Any idea how to implement it simply?

Comment: The answer Teddichiiwa gave is a good one. The above answer says, although basic. The last part of code: Uuid().v4() adds a unique ID:

// Generate a v4 (random) id
uuid.v4(); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'

This will always be different. So my guess is to change whatever ID identifier you have when you add the item to your card, and change it to that code.

Personally I would add a String uniqueID to my class and when I add the item to the card, use the unique generated code for it.

Comment: This does work, however, it will display an ugly string of UUID. Is there a way to make it invisible, but still register as a unique string? Maybe adding a string to class would work as you mentioned.

Comment: If you want to properly add items, then you should do it with an identifier in your model. Right now you are adding the item with a string identifier:  model.addCartItem("${name.name}\n${name.description}"), So it will show as a String and be ugly, yes. You will probably need to rebuild it but since I don't know what you are exactly doing I can't iterate further. Are you saving just the String? or an Object? where is it going? Just to a list or database? or firestore?

Comment: Here's the thread that might explain a bit more, I literally need the ability to add each item as many times as I want, without being duplicate keys: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65071710/adding-multiple-list-tile-items-in-flutter-to-list/65072376#65072376

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040880/making-unique-id-list-tile-in-flutter/65042342#65042342